# Why do we need Kies (ADB driver) in Windows but not in Linux?

Tags: adb, linux, samsung-kies, windows

Why do we need an ADB driver in Windows but not in Linux?

I have been working on Android for the past few months in Windows. To run my project on my Samsung device I had to install Kies first. Similarly for my LG device there is a LG ADB driver, and another for HTC.

But when I shifted to Ubuntu Linux recently, I didn't require any other drivers like Kies and ADB. I was able to debug directly without any third party driver. Why is that?

I know it is something very common, but I haven't found anything which explains why this is the case.

Comment: added update #2 to my answer

Answer (score 5):

[Chor WaiChun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1131470/chor-waichun) mentioned this on a [locked question you posted on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273274/why-we-need-kiesadb-driver-in-windows-not-in-linux):

> I've seen somewhere stated that this behaviour is because both android
>   and linux run on same kernel, and same situation goes to developing
>   android on mac. Both OS runs in very similar OS kernel with Android,
>   that is why they don't need any drivers. These are just something I
>   remembered seeing from other threads, can't give 100% sure

**UPDATE #1:** The [Android site](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) also mentions this:

> If you are developing on Windows and would like to connect an
>   Android-powered device to test your applications, then you need to
>   install the appropriate USB driver. ...
>
> **If you're developing on Mac OS X or Linux, then you probably don't need to install a USB driver.** To start developing with your device,
>   read Using Hardware Devices.

**UPDATE #2:** There's a [comment on StackOverflow](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33004/linux-adb-driver-for-lg-viper-lg-ls840#comment62737_33009) regarding `libusb`. I think this may be the reason why Linux does not need additional drivers.

> Actually adb under Linux accesses USB devices using libusb without any
>   specific kernel driver. Also adb has a list of vendor IDs which it is
>   allowed to use, but this does not explain the problem in question,
>   because vendor IDs for both phones are the same. And in case of
>   permission problems due to missing udev rules adb devices clearly
>   shows “no permissions” in the list, so this is also not the cause of
>   this problem.

Comment: my question is why? Do you have some links and all so that i can get total idea, +1 for the answer though!

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure why Linux doesn't typically require a specific ADB driver.

However, there is a "universal" Windows USB ADB driver that works with most Android devices.  It was developed by Koushik Dutta (Koush), a famous Android developer who works on ClockworkMod.  It should work quite well for you.  Download here:  http://koush.com/post/universal-adb-driver

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, My question is why is this behavior , And i know about universal ADB driver.

Answer (score 0):

As others already responded, in linux there is common USB driver, which adb uses. It seems that in Windows there is no common USB driver, so adb uses the "provided" driver - different for every device/manufacturer.

Comment: In Windows there's no universal driver *pre-installed*. There's one available however, as [Neil pointed out](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/51346/16575). On the other side: There's no Kies on Linux, so you need no Kies driver #D